# PHP syntax highlighting code editor

Tags: php, javascript, syntax-highlighting

I need a configureable and extendable in browser code editor using JS and/or PHP (no python or flash etc).

Something like code.google.com editor (it rocks!) and I really like the diff capability it provides. It would be cool but I can't find info on what editor it is employing.

Anyone know something like that? Or if code.google.com's code is open Source? If yes, where can I get it?

Comment: i found ace editor http://ace.ajax.org/ . anybody got expirience with it, is it customisable ? and also are there other syntaxes for it (i really need it to do C# of other things:P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has been previously answered with [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/) being the preferred choice and it is apparently used by [Googles code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/). See [Is there a good in-browser code editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198271/is-there-a-good-in-browser-code-editor) for more information.

Comment: well i tried it some time ago (edit:must have been something with a similar name cause it looked nothing like this 1) for another project and it just... didnt work. but ill try again now. thx

Comment: OH ! it actually is code.google.com editor. well then thats solved :)